# Can't read bagfile containing custom messages

Tags: ros, rosbag, bagfile, bagfiles

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag file with video and imu data defined with custom messages that I want to read (especially topics /capture and /imu_raw). I know from documentation what the structure of the custom messages is. How can I read the data? 
 Doing **rosbag info** on the file shows:

```
types:    
libks/ImageSet             [b3ef08c9cff052c83f5039d098add069] 
pximu/AttitudeData         [bc609da5ddac9016c096c67da33d8b9c] 
pximu/RawIMUData           [0380911195329d307d8f033bc714dbbf] 
[...]

topics:  
/attitude                2174 msgs    : pximu/AttitudeData 
/capture                 3282 msgs    : libks/ImageSet  
/imu_raw                 10873 msgs   : pximu/RawIMUData
[...]
```

I cannot play the file with 'rosbag play', probably because rosbag doesn't know the message definitions. Therefore, I thought I needed to use migration(see http_wiki_ros_org/rosbag_migration) and provide custom message definitions (see http_wiki_ros_org/msg) and use them in a rule file. I made a new package 'bag_analyser", and added the custom messages to the 'msg' folder and compiled. E.g. for ImageSet I made a file ImageSet.msg:

```
Header header
sensor_msgs/Image[] images
```

This seems to work, e.g. for **' rosmsg show bag_analyser/ImageSet'** I get:

```
std_msgs/Header header
uint32 seq
time stamp
string frame_id
sensor_msgs/Image[] images
std_msgs/Header header
uint32 seq
time stamp
string frame_id
uint32 height
uint32 width
string encoding
uint8 is_bigendian
uint32 step
uint8[] data
```

I also made messages for RawIMUData and AttitudeData. Then I generated a rules file (rules.bmr, see full output at end), adjusted the rules that needed to be adjusted and executed:

```
rosbag fix original_bag.bag converted_bag.bag rules.bmr
```

which told me "bag migrated successfully". Doing **rosbag info** on the converted file gives me:

```
types:       bag_analyser/AttitudeData       [bc609da5ddac9016c096c67da33d8b9c]
             bag_analyser/ImageSet           [b3ef08c9cff052c83f5039d098add069]
             bag_analyser/RawIMUData         [0380911195329d307d8f033bc714dbbf]
[...]
topics:      /attitude                     2174 msgs    : bag_analyser/AttitudeData      
             /capture                      3282 msgs    : bag_analyser/ImageSet          
             /imu_raw                     10873 msgs    : bag_analyser/RawIMUData
```

My problem is that I still cannot read the file. I tried using **'rosbag play'** but it simply gives me:

```
[ INFO] [1402332944.127314834]: Opening converted_bag.bag
[FATAL] [1402332944.127848761]: Error opening file: converted_bag.bag
```

### I also tried reading in the file using the rosbag API, which also fails opening the file (code in image_converter.cpp below). I changed the bagfile's permissions and set it to allow read/write/execute just to make sure it wasn't that. **What am I doing wrong?  How can I read the data from the file?** I am fairly new to ROS, so any help or tips are greatly appreciated!

**File listings:**

folder bag/analyser/msg
ImageSet.msg

```
Header header    
sensor_msgs/Image[] images
```

RawIMUData.msg

```
Header header
# Measured accelerations (in x, y, z)
Vector3f acc

# Measured angular speeds (around x, y, z)
Vector3f gyro

# Measured magnetic field (around x , y, z)
Vector3f mag
```

Vector3f.msg

```
float32 x
float32 y
float32 z
```

AttitudeData.msg

```
Header header

# roll angle [rad]
float32 roll

# pitch angle [rad]
float32 pitch

# yaw angle [rad]
float32 yaw

# roll angular speed [rad/s]
float32 rollspeed

# pitch angular speed [rad/s]
float32 pitchspeed

# yaw angular speed [rad/s]
float32 yawspeed
```

bag_analyser/image_converter.cpp ( includes message definition for ImageSet.h and tries to use rosbag API to read file):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <rosbag/view.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <bag_analyser/ImageSet.h>

static const std::string OPENCV_WINDOW = "Image window";

void loadBag() {

    rosbag::Bag bag("~/robotics/rosbook/src/bag_analyser/bag/converted_bag.bag"); // fails here
    
    std::string l_cam_image = "/capture";
    std::vector<std::string> topics;
    topics.push_back(l_cam_image);
    
    rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));
    
    BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
    {
        if (m.getTopic() == l_cam_image || ("/" + m.getTopic() == l_cam_image)) 
        {
            boost::shared_ptr<bag_analyser::ImageSet> image_array = 
                 m.instantiate<bag_analyser::ImageSet >();
            bag_analyser::ImageSet* theSetPtr = image_array.get();
            bag_analyser::ImageSet theSet = *theSetPtr;
            cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
            try
            {
              cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(theSetPtr->images[0], sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
            }
            catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
            {
              ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
              return;
            }
            // Update GUI Window
            cv::imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
            cv::waitKey(3); 
        }
    }
    bag.close();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_converter");
  loadBag();
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

bag_analyser/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(bag_analyser)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  message_generation
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  rosbag
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   ImageSet.msg
   RawIMUData.msg
   Vector3f.msg
   AttitudeData.msg
 )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
   sensor_msgs
 )

## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
)
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(image_converter src/image_converter.cpp)

target_link_libraries ( image_converter ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

rules.bmr

```
class update_pximu_RawIMUData_0380911195329d307d8f033bc714dbbf(MessageUpdateRule):
    old_type = "pximu/RawIMUData"
    old_full_text = """
Header header
# Measured accelerations (in x, y, z)
Vector3f acc

# Measured angular speeds (around x, y, z)
Vector3f gyro

# Measured magnetic field (around x , y, z)
Vector3f mag


================================================================================
MSG: std_msgs/Header
# Standard metadata for higher-level stamped data types.
# This is generally used to communicate timestamped data 
# in a particular coordinate frame.
# 
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID 
uint32 seq
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:
# * stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch
# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds since stamp_secs
# time-handling sugar is provided by the client library
time stamp
#Frame this data is associated with
# 0: no frame
# 1: global frame
string frame_id

================================================================================
MSG: pximu/Vector3f
float32 x
float32 y
float32 z
"""

    new_type = "bag_analyser/RawIMUData"
    new_full_text = """
Header header
# Measured accelerations (in x, y, z)
Vector3f acc

# Measured angular speeds (around x, y, z)
Vector3f gyro

# Measured magnetic field (around x , y, z)
Vector3f mag


================================================================================
MSG: std_msgs/Header
# Standard metadata for higher-level stamped data types.
# This is generally used to communicate timestamped data 
# in a particular coordinate frame.
# 
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID 
uint32 seq
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:
# * stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch
# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds since stamp_secs
# time-handling sugar is provided by the client library
time stamp
#Frame this data is associated with
# 0: no frame
# 1: global frame
string frame_id

================================================================================
MSG: bag_analyser/Vector3f
float32 x
float32 y
float32 z
"""

    order = 0
    migrated_types = [
        ("Header","Header"),]

    valid = True

    def update(self, old_msg, new_msg):
        self.migrate(old_msg.header, new_msg.header)
        #No migration path between [Vector3f] and [Vector3f]
        new_msg.acc = self.get_new_class('bag_analyser/Vector3f')(old_msg.acc)
        #No migration path between [Vector3f] and [Vector3f]
        new_msg.gyro = self.get_new_class('bag_analyser/Vector3f')(old_msg.gyro)
        #No migration path between [Vector3f] and [Vector3f]
        new_msg.mag = self.get_new_class('bag_analyser/Vector3f')(old_msg.mag)
class update_libks_ImageSet_b3ef08c9cff052c83f5039d098add069(MessageUpdateRule):
    old_type = "libks/ImageSet"
    old_full_text = """
Header header

sensor_msgs/Image[] images

================================================================================
MSG: std_msgs/Header
# Standard metadata for higher-level stamped data types.
# This is generally used to communicate timestamped data 
# in a particular coordinate frame.
# 
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID 
uint32 seq
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:
# * stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch
# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds since stamp_secs
# time-handling sugar is provided by the client library
time stamp
#Frame this data is associated with
# 0: no frame
# 1: global frame
string frame_id

================================================================================
MSG: sensor_msgs/Image
# This message contains an uncompressed image
# (0, 0) is at top-left corner of image
#

Header header        # Header timestamp should be acquisition time of image
                     # Header frame_id should be optical frame of camera
                     # origin of frame should be optical center of cameara
                     # +x should point to the right in the image
                     # +y should point down in the image
                     # +z should point into to plane of the image
                     # If the frame_id here and the frame_id of the CameraInfo
                     # message associated with the image conflict
                     # the behavior is undefined

uint32 height         # image height, that is, number of rows
uint32 width          # image width, that is, number of columns

# The legal values for encoding are in file src/image_encodings.cpp
# If you want to standardize a new string format, join
# ros-users@lists.sourceforge.net and send an email proposing a new encoding.

string encoding       # Encoding of pixels -- channel meaning, ordering, size
                      # taken from the list of strings in src/image_encodings.cpp

uint8 is_bigendian    # is this data bigendian?
uint32 step           # Full row length in bytes
uint8[] data          # actual matrix data, size is (step * rows)
"""

    new_type = "bag_analyser/ImageSet"
    new_full_text = """
Header header

sensor_msgs/Image[] images

================================================================================
MSG: std_msgs/Header
# Standard metadata for higher-level stamped data types.
# This is generally used to communicate timestamped data 
# in a particular coordinate frame.
# 
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID 
uint32 seq
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:
# * stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch
# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds since stamp_secs
# time-handling sugar is provided by the client library
time stamp
#Frame this data is associated with
# 0: no frame
# 1: global frame
string frame_id

================================================================================
MSG: sensor_msgs/Image
# This message contains an uncompressed image
# (0, 0) is at top-left corner of image
#

Header header        # Header timestamp should be acquisition time of image
                     # Header frame_id should be optical frame of camera
                     # origin of frame should be optical center of cameara
                     # +x should point to the right in the image
                     # +y should point down in the image
                     # +z should point into to plane of the image
                     # If the frame_id here and the frame_id of the CameraInfo
                     # message associated with the image conflict
                     # the behavior is undefined

uint32 height         # image height, that is, number of rows
uint32 width          # image width, that is, number of columns

# The legal values for encoding are in file src/image_encodings.cpp
# If you want to standardize a new string format, join
# ros-users@lists.sourceforge.net and send an email proposing a new encoding.

string encoding       # Encoding of pixels -- channel meaning, ordering, size
                      # taken from the list of strings in include/sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h

uint8 is_bigendian    # is this data bigendian?
uint32 step           # Full row length in bytes
uint8[] data          # actual matrix data, size is (step * rows)
"""

    order = 0
    migrated_types = [
        ("Header","Header"),
        ("sensor_msgs/Image","sensor_msgs/Image"),]

    valid = True

    def update(self, old_msg, new_msg):
        self.migrate(old_msg.header, new_msg.header)
        self.migrate_array(old_msg.images, new_msg.images, "sensor_msgs/Image")
class update_pximu_AttitudeData_bc609da5ddac9016c096c67da33d8b9c(MessageUpdateRule):
    old_type = "pximu/AttitudeData"
    old_full_text = """
Header header

# roll angle [rad]
float32 roll

# pitch angle [rad]
float32 pitch

# yaw angle [rad]
float32 yaw

# roll angular speed [rad/s]
float32 rollspeed

# pitch angular speed [rad/s]
float32 pitchspeed

# yaw angular speed [rad/s]
float32 yawspeed

================================================================================
MSG: std_msgs/Header
# Standard metadata for higher-level stamped data types.
# This is generally used to communicate timestamped data 
# in a particular coordinate frame.
# 
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID 
uint32 seq
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:
# * stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch
# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds since stamp_secs
# time-handling sugar is provided by the client library
time stamp
#Frame this data is associated with
# 0: no frame
# 1: global frame
string frame_id
"""

    new_type = "bag_analyser/AttitudeData"
    new_full_text = """
Header header

# roll angle [rad]
float32 roll

# pitch angle [rad]
float32 pitch

# yaw angle [rad]
float32 yaw

# roll angular speed [rad/s]
float32 rollspeed

# pitch angular speed [rad/s]
float32 pitchspeed

# yaw angular speed [rad/s]
float32 yawspeed

================================================================================
MSG: std_msgs/Header
# Standard metadata for higher-level stamped data types.
# This is generally used to communicate timestamped data 
# in a particular coordinate frame.
# 
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID 
uint32 seq
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:
# * stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch
# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds since stamp_secs
# time-handling sugar is provided by the client library
time stamp
#Frame this data is associated with
# 0: no frame
# 1: global frame
string frame_id
"""

    order = 0
    migrated_types = [
        ("Header","Header"),]

    valid = True

    def update(self, old_msg, new_msg):
        self.migrate(old_msg.header, new_msg.header)
        new_msg.roll = old_msg.roll
        new_msg.pitch = old_msg.pitch
        new_msg.yaw = old_msg.yaw
        new_msg.rollspeed = old_msg.rollspeed
        new_msg.pitchspeed = old_msg.pitchspeed
        new_msg.yawspeed = old_msg.yawspeed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173239/can%27t-read-bagfile-containing-custom-messages/) by [Ketill](https://answers.ros.org/users/18832/ketill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-06-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The trick is to make empty packages with the same name as the packages of the message that you need, and then add the custom message definition to these packages. So in my case I made a package 'pximu' and added the custom message definition for AttitudeData and RawIMUData to it. Then I made a 'libks' package and added the custom message definition for ImageSet to it. After compiling I could read those messages with 'rosbag play'.

---

Originally posted by [Ketill](https://answers.ros.org/users/18832/ketill/) with karma: 36 on 2014-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1